# How to edit my-account-link in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, link

I'm using Magento 2. I tried to edit the `my-account-link` element ("My Account" link in the top bar), I just want to change the text with an icon but I can't find the `phtml` file to edit!

I've tried to enable the path hints but doesn't take me to the proper file to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is set from the xml file at below location :

```
/magento-root/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

--

```
 <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
        </arguments>
  </block>
```

Comment: that works, thank you for your time ! what about the Sign In one ? I've tryed to see the other files but didn't found it..

Comment: the label `Sign in` is set from `/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/AuthorizationLink.php`

Comment: Thank you , I've added the AuthorizationLink to my top nav with this line in default.xml <move element="authorization-link" destination="header.panel" after="minicart.topnav"/>   how do I add it also for the mobile nav ?